# Pass Special character in Contains() in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using contains() for search a string.

My Product table having 3 columns(Product_id,Product_name,Price);

I want to search 40" LCD

My Table contains 40" LCD,40' LCD, 40cm LCD etc 
I am searching 40" LCD a product using below query.

```
Select top 10 *
from Product
where contains(Product_name,'(FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, 40) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, LCD))')
```

The above query shows a zero result. But I want to result like 40" LCD

how to pass special characters in Contains()?

I searched in Google but not found any good solutions

Please help to solve this one.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

To use the Full Text Search properly and only return `40" LCD`, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Product_name, '40 AND LCD')
AND Product_name LIKE '%40"%'
```

NOTE: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), punctuation is ignored, so the above query will include `40"` and `40'`.

> Punctuation is ignored. Therefore, CONTAINS(testing, "computer
>   failure") matches a row with the value, "Where is my computer? Failure
>   to find it would be expensive." For more information on word-breaker
>   behavior, see [Configure and Manage Word Breakers and Stemmers for Search.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx)

And in the case where this is no FTS, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Product
WHERE Product_name LIKE '%40%LCD%'
```

Comment: `Like '%...'` won't use an index.

Comment: Correct, you'd need to add Full Text Search to the column(s) concerned (which appears to have been done in this case) and then do it that way to be able to use any index.

Comment: They already have full text search but it isn't working as they want in this case. That is the whole point of the question.

Comment: using contains can we solve this issue.Actually like will take more time and i also need full text search.

Comment: Nice answer @Dommer but I think you last edited one will take more time then simple like operator bcz in that query both LIKE and CONTAINS() operators are using.can you please edit to good performance query.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan and have you timed it? It should be really fast as it uses the index and then refines those results with the `LIKE` operator. It should be the fastest way of doing it. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

It will search for any row which Contains Double Quot or Single Quot.

Suppose You have Table Like :

```
create table a(
f1 varchar(100))

insert into a values('40" Inch TV')

select * from a 
where CHARINDEX('"',f1,1)>0

select * from a 
where CHARINDEX('40"',f1,1)>0
```

And, this is for single Quoted Data

```
insert into a values('17'' inch monitor')

select * from a 
where CHARINDEX('17''',f1,1)>0
```